# What is the difference between having a proxy on model or store in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've seen a few examples where the proxy is not only declared on the store but also the model.
This seems a little redundant to me.  Why would you need to have the proxy set on both? What are the advantages to having it on the model instead of the store and vice-versa?

Comment: How about you show us these examples you're talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Answer from Mitchell Simoens in Sencha Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?177591-Proxy-in-Model-vs.-Store) :

> Technically there really isn't a difference. The store will look for
>   the proxy config on itself and if none is present look for it on the
>   model. If you want to use Models by themselves (like for forms) then
>   having the proxy on the model will allow you to still use the proxy.

Hope this helps